# Using Apple ProximityReader Framework with Adyen API

Tags: adyen, tap-to-pay

Would like to use Apples ProximityReader Framework to perform card reads for Apple Tap to Pay.

1. Is it possible to use the ProximityReader Framework with Adyen as with Stripe this isn't possible.
2. Using the ProximityReader framework you get "A Base64-encoded string that contains the encrypted payment information to send to your payment provider."
   Adyen's payment API transaction with paymentMethod ApplePayDetails takes an applePayToken - "The stringified and base64 encoded paymentData you retrieved from the Apple framework."
   so would this payment request work if i provide it the card read from ProximityReader